# Как поместить RadioButton в switch?

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте!
В методе есть две переменные(операнда) и оператор. Каждая RadioButton соответствует своему оператору. При выборе одной из RadioButton между операндами должен подставляться свой оператор. Уместен ли в такой ситуации switch? И как его прописать?

Comment: В учебном материале для каждой кнопки прописывается отдельный метод для события выбора. Считаю это слишком громоздким

Comment: Вы используете события? Какие?

Comment: @volk11051994 можно узнать, почему вы считаете предложенным способ громоздким?

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду под словом «оператор»?

Comment: Я новичок и могу ошибаться в терминологии. @Андрей Под событиями Я имел ввиду методы, работающие при выборе кнопки (слово событие как понимаю было не уместно).

Comment: @VladD Под операторами имел ввиду бинарные операции.

Comment: @Foggy Finder Мне показалось это громоздким, т.к. один метод переписывается энное кол-во раз, заменяя одну деталь. Я подумал что лаконичнее будет написать один метод и заменять в нем эту деталь в зависимости от выбора. Хочу узнать как это реализовать и проверить какой способ лучше

Comment: Добавьте пример метода в текст вопроса. Если вы используете события - вы можете привязать один и тот же обработчик ко всем `RadioButton`

Comment: @volk11051994 не переживайте, вы вполне уместно использовали слово "события"

Comment: @volk11051994 все верно, можно использовать одно события (или команду) для каждого из radioButton. А оператор хранить в Tag (или передавать в качестве параметра в случае с командами)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

советую вам группировать элементы например в панеле,a после этого делать enumeration.
Example:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="radioPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="38,68,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100">
            <RadioButton Content="RadioButton"/>
            <RadioButton Content="RadioButton"/>
            <RadioButton Content="RadioButton"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем кто помог разобраться! Благодаря вашим подсказкам узнал несколько новых фич в с# и xaml. Написал вот такую простенькую программку. Пока не ясно как правильно объявить переменные, выдаёт cs0236 для int.Parse(LeftVar.Text); и int rightOp = int.Parse(RightVar.Text);

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
        public enum ButtonsCheck { Check1, Check2, Check3, Check4, Check5 }
        int leftOp = int.Parse(LeftVar.Text);
        int rightOp = int.Parse(RightVar.Text);
        int result = 0;

    private void Calculated_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Result.Text = $"Результат: {result.ToString()}";
    }

    private void RadioButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ButtonsCheck checks = (ButtonsCheck)(new Random()).Next(0, 4);
          switch(checks)
        {
            case ButtonsCheck.Check1:
                AddValues();
                break;
            case ButtonsCheck.Check2:
                SubtractValues();
                break;
            case ButtonsCheck.Check3:
                MultiplayValues();
                break;
            case ButtonsCheck.Check4:
                DivideValues();
                break;
            case ButtonsCheck.Check5:
                RemainderValues();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void AddValues()
    {
        result = leftOp + rightOp;
        Expression.Text = $"Выражение: {LeftVar.Text} + {RightVar.Text}";
    }

    private void SubtractValues()
    {
        result = leftOp - rightOp;
        Expression.Text = $"Выражение: {LeftVar.Text} - {RightVar.Text}";
    }

    private void MultiplayValues()
    {
        result = leftOp * rightOp;
        Expression.Text = $"Выражение: {LeftVar.Text} * {RightVar.Text}";
    }

    private void DivideValues()
    {
        result = leftOp / rightOp;
        Expression.Text = $"Выражение: {LeftVar.Text} / {RightVar.Text}";
    }

    private void RemainderValues()
    {
        result = leftOp % rightOp;
        Expression.Text = $"Выражение: {LeftVar.Text} % {RightVar.Text}";
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Зря Random в свойстве прописал, switch работает, только результат случайный